# ClickOnce Application in IIS7

Tags: .net, winforms, iis-7, clickonce

Can anybody help me to deploy ClickOnce application to IIS7?

Comment: Did you try it yourself? If so, what's going wrong? If not, why not? In short: we need more info :)

Answer (score 3):

This walks you through it: http://luppes.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/clickonce-deployment-projects-and-iis-7/

Comment: There is a reason why only providing a link is a bad answer. The link is now dead.